# Reusing docker image in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've seen the following in https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/11/15/celery-docker/

Which reuses the built image I believe

```
services: 
  worker:
    build: .
    image: &img worker 
 
  beat:
    build: .
    image: *img
```

Since I'm using `Dockerfile`, I can do something like this, I see it's rebuilding the image (`pip install` in Dockerfile runs twice for each service)

```
 services:
   worker:
     build:
       context: ../../
       dockerfile: ./retention/docker/celery/Dockerfile
     image: &img worker
     container_name: celery
     # command: [celery, worker, --app=app1, --loglevel=INFO]


   beat:
     build:
       context: ../../
       dockerfile: ./retention/docker/celery/Dockerfile
     image: *img
     # command: [celery, beat, --app=app1, --loglevel=INFO]
```

How can I build just one image and reuse it?

Comment: I find it actually rebuild,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the same :

```
image: myimage:mytag
```

for the both services

then `docker-compose build` will use cache

Answer (score 4):

You can re-use the same image in the same docker-compose but the order will mater, what if the image is not built yet and **service B** starting with that image that not exist yet which is supposed to be built in **service A** stage?

So add [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) will help this race case also remove the build context from the beat service.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  worker:
    image: worker_beat
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: ./retention/docker/celery/Dockerfile
    container_name: celery
    command: [celery, beat, --app=app1, --loglevel=INFO
  beat:
    image: worker_beat
    depends_on:
      - worker 
    command: [celery, beat, --app=app1, --loglevel=INFO]
```

to run your stack you will just need `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: This right here should be accepted answer ^